# How to implements touch in j2me game(Menuscreen)

Tags: java-me, touch

I developed game in j2me without touch. Now i want to implement the touch in my game . I used  `pointerPressed` and `pointerRealesed` in game. I draw the string (start,highscore,about,exit) in menuscreen. How to implement the touch in menuscreen.

when i touch that start , the game will start . Any examples ?

I used `poiterPressed(x,y)` postion for start,highscore . Its the correct way ?

eg:

```
protected void pointerPressed(int x, int y) {

    System.out.println("The value of x and y is "+x+"----"+y);

    if((x>86&&y<150))
    {
        state=STATE_Game;

    }      

if(x>187&&y<10)

    {

        state=Highscore;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The touch handling events are present in the `javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas package.` They are:

- **hasPointerEvents()**

  Returns: boolean

  Description: Returns true if device supports touch-screen input.
- **hasPointerMotionEvents()**

  Returns: boolean

  Description: Returns true if device supports detection of press, release and drag events.
- **pointerPressed(int x, int y)**

  Returns: void

  Description: Invoked when a press event is triggered. The x and y variables will contain the coordinates of the location which was pressed.
- **pointerReleased(int x, int y)**

  Returns: void

  Description: Similar to `pointerPressed()` except that it is invoked when the stylus/finger is released from the screen.
- **PointerDragged()**

  Returns: void

  Description: Invoked in response to a drag event

(Strictly, these are not touch-screen events specifically. They could relate to any kind of pointer-based input, like a mouse or trackball. However, I have only seen them supported on touch-screen devices.)

You need no specific JSRs. These features are standard in MIDP-1.0 and later. Since they exist on all MIDP devices, you do not need a specific "touch" version of your application.

Look at some examples,

[How scroll an image?](http://www.jappit.com/blog/2008/10/06/touch-and-j2me-part-1-how-scroll-an-image/)

[Coding Touchscreen Scrolling in Java ME](http://www.substanceofcode.com/2009/07/29/coding-touchscreen-scrolling-in-java-me/)

Comment: I able to used pointerPressed and pointerRealsed in my game. How to used in menu screen. If i set x any y postion mean , when i going for porting its make very difficult. In every device i need to check x and y postion ?

Comment: @JohnRaja: Look at this article, [LCDUI components in touch interaction](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-06525750-39A7-4165-A711-80CC0D97487A.html).